# How can I have Azure Devops Yaml cron pipeline properly scheduled?

Tags: azure-devops, cron, continuous-integration, yaml

I have a yaml pipeline that is meant to run every day at midnight.

Here is how the schedule is written :

```
schedules:
- cron: "0 0 * * *"
  displayName: Daily midnight run
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  always: true
```

But when I have a look at the logs I see that the pipeline does not run at midnight as expected.

I checked the syntax several times and I did not spot any error.

My workaround for the moment was to override my Yaml definition usint the GUI scheduler.

Comment: Did you see that "The time zone for cron schedules is UTC, so in these examples, the midnight build and the noon build are at midnight and noon in UTC."? Also: could you share what you see when you look at the preview of upcoming scheduled builds? Click "Scheduled runs" from the context menu on the pipeline details page for your pipeline.

Comment: What OS are you working with? Any info from the logs? are process reaching crond?